# Obtain Micronaut ResourceLoader in Method Call

Tags: kotlin, dependency-injection, micronaut

I'm trying to get ahold of a ResourceLoader for a utility method by using injections, but I keep getting the following error:

```
Caused by: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property resourceResolver has not been initialized
```

```
@Singleton
class Injections {
    @Inject
    lateinit var resourceResolver: ResourceLoader
}

val inj = Injections()

fun <T> parseYaml(filePath: String): T {
    if (!inj.resourceResolver.getResource(filePath).isPresent) {
        throw IllegalArgumentException("Could not find file '$filePath'")
    }
    val inputStream = inj.resourceResolver.getResourceAsStream(filePath).get()
    return Yaml().load(inputStream) as T
}
```

I don't need to be using injections to make this happen, I just need to access a ResourceResolver from the parseYaml method.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't need to be using injections to make this happen

You kind of do need to be using injections.  That is why your code makes use of `@Inject`.

The problem is you are creating a new instance of `Injections` instead of using the one provided by the container, so your instance won't be initialized the way you want it to be.  Instead of `val inj = Injections()` if you `@Inject` the `Injections` instance into whatever bean(s) need access to it, that will work.

Comment: I'm fairly new to Java, so I'm not sure what this means. Do I need to create a new class which contains the parsing function?

Comment: "Do I need to create a new class which contains the parsing function?" - Not necessarily.  You could put the function in an existing class.